# How do I prevent the image inside the CollapsingToolBarLayout from moving during collapse?

Tags: android

Hey so one of the requirements is to have the image fixed during the collapse phase of the CollapsingToolBarLayout and I have no idea how to achieve this. Can someone please help?

CoordinateLayout Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_collapse_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image_holder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:src="@drawable/image_112"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/back_arrow_white"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!--Child 2-->

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: post you full code of your layout and give some example what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I was able to achieve what I wanted to but putting the following line of code under the imageview.

```
app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="1.0"
```

This leads to the image not moving while the layout is collapsing